# Powershell error: Missing file specification after redirection operator

Tags: powershell, docker

I just started tutorial of Docker and after download and followed the command on the official homepage that

```
PS C:\COCcal> cat > Dockerfile <<EOF
>> FROM busybox
>> CMD echo "Hello world! This is my first Docker image."
>> EOF
```

gives me

```
At line:1 char:19
+ cat > Dockerfile <<EOF
+                   ~
Missing file specification after redirection operator.
At line:1 char:18
+ cat > Dockerfile <<EOF
+                  ~
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
At line:1 char:19
+ cat > Dockerfile <<EOF
+                   ~
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
At line:2 char:1
+ FROM busybox
+ ~~~~
The 'from' keyword is not supported in this version of the language.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingFileSpecification
```

This error. I searched error message on google but cannot find the same case with me. Is any setup is missing? or what do I have to do to work those commands? I appreciate it in advance.

Comment: These are linux shell commands and not PowerShell commands. Why are you running them in PowerShell?

Comment: If you ***really want*** to do this in PowerShell, just use `Set-Content Dockerfile`, then at the prompts enter your data. When you want the close the file, just press Enter on an empty line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are running Linux shell commands inside of PowerShell. Depending on your configuration, that could be problematic. I would suggest opening a Linux shell or using commands that are supported by PowerShell.

```
# Run the Set-Content Command Below
Set-Content -Path Dockerfile

# After Running the above command, I am prompted to enter data:
Value[0]: FROM busybox
Value[1]: CMD echo "Hello world! This is my first Docker image."
Value[2]:
```

When you run the command above, you will be prompted for `Value[0]`, `Value[1]`, etc. (provided you press Enter after entering data on each line) until you press Enter on a line without any other input. Each of those inputs will be on a separate line in `Dockerfile`.

Regarding [Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7) operators in PowerShell, only `>`, `>>`, and `>&1` are supported. If `cat` works at all, it is because it is an alias. You can run `Get-Alias cat` to see which command it maps to. On my system, that is `Get-Content`.

---

There are other PowerShell ways to accomplish this task provided you don't need to have the same experience given by the Linux commands. Below is just one example.

```
$Content = @'
line 1 stuff
line 2 stuff
line 3 stuff
'@
$Content | Set-Content -Path Dockerfile
```

See below for outputting with `UTF8NoBOM` encoding.

```
$Content = @'
line 1 stuff
line 2 stuff
line 3 stuff
'@
[IO.File]::WriteAllLines('C:\COCcal\Dockerfile',$Content,[Text.UTF8Encoding]::new($false))
```

---

I can't speak for running this Docker configuration with respect to Docker. So there could be some things to consider when trying to run the native PowerShell commands.

1. If `Dockerfile` requires certain end of line characters to be present, [Set-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-7) may use some combination of carriage returns and newline characters on each line that Docker does not like.
2. Docker may expect a certain encoding of `Dockerfile`. While `Set-Content` does offer the `-Encoding` parameter, it still may not provide what you need. For example, you could use `-Encoding UTF8`. In Windows PowerShell, that will be UTF8 with BOM (there is not a No BOM option with this command in Windows PowerShell). The default encoding in Windows PowerShell will be `Default`, which is likely `ANSI`. In PowerShell Core, the default encoding is `UTF8NoBOM`.

Answer (score -1):

There's no << operator in powershell. cat might be an alias for get-content.